# How do I mock or stub a method from a readonly property whose datatype is dictionary?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am starting out on the rhino mocks and ran into a compounded problem.

I have a dependency on a class AppDefaults which has a readonly property "Properties" with datatype of Dictionary.

My Class under test uses the result of a Dictionary function .ContainsKey() which returns a boolean.

MyAppDefaultsInstance.Properties.ContainsKey("DefaultKey")

I only got around this by creating a public virtual function on the class under test to wrap the .Contains function. But is there a way to Mock or stub .ContainsKey result without having a wrapper to mock it?

Example Code:

```
    public class AppDefaults
{

    public readonly IDictionary<String, String> Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public AppDefaults()
    {
        LoadProperties();
    }

    private void LoadProperties()
    {
        //load the properties;
    }

    public virtual int GetPropertyAsInt(string propertyKey)
    {
        return XmlConvert.ToInt32(Properties[propertyKey]);
    }

}


public class DefaultManager
{
    AppDefaults _appsDefault;
    public int TheDefaultSize
    {
        get
        {
            int systemMax;
            int currentDefault = 10;

            if (_appsDefault.Properties.ContainsKey("DefaultKey"))
            {
                systemMax = _appsDefault.GetPropertyAsInt("DefaultKey");
            }
            else
            {
                systemMax = currentDefault;
            }

            return systemMax;
        }
    }

    public DefaultManager(AppDefaults appDef) {
        _appsDefault = appDef;
    }
}

[TestClass()]
public class DefaultManagerTest
{

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TheDefaultSizeTest()
    {
        var appdef = MockRepository.GenerateStub<AppDefaults>();

        appdef.Expect(m => m.Properties.ContainsKey("DefaultKey")).Return(true);

        appdef.Stub(app_def => app_def.GetPropertyAsInt("DefaultKey")).Return(2);

        DefaultManager target = new DefaultManager(appdef); 

        int actual;
        actual = target.TheDefaultSize;
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mocking the `.ContainsKey` method why don't you just populate the dictionary with some predefined value for the test:

```
// arrange
var appDef = new AppDefaults();
appDef.Properties["DefaultKey"] = "2";

// act
var target = new DefaultManager(appDef); 

// assert
Assert.AreEqual(target.TheDefaultSize, 2);
```

Comment: If your definition of a unit test is to mock all .NET built-in collection methods then you will hardly ever write a single unit test :-)

Comment: AppDefaults in the example is not .NET build-in class. Your solution will work but it little bit to coupled.

Comment: Anyway, your solution also does the job. :)

Comment: I had a bad assumption on the back of my head that the "readonly" would get in the way of me doing that and assignment is underhanded somehow. I'm guess since its not the real object, a mock can be injected with anything which makes sense.. Thank you.

Comment: I think I have to correct myself here. I believe the "read-only" only attribute relates to the dictionary declaration. In other words, its like me giving someone a notepad, that person can read and write on it, but the notepad cannot be replaced by another.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expose

```
AppDefaults.Properties
```

field.
Instead of that you can add a method like

```
GetProperty(string key)
```

to AppDefaults (that will return the key if it exists and so on) and mock it's result in your unit test. Mocked method will return the value that you will check **target.TheDefaultSize** against.

Comment: I agree, this was the solution i first came up with at first. However, the original writers of the code had it public for some reason. I do not like how it's written but its not worth refactoring code at this point. I'm merely doing things for the proof of concept.